# Is it possible to index arrays using strings or characters?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

For example,

```
double myArray[3] = {0.0};

myArray["SSN_1"] = 2.0;
myArray["SSN_2"] = 3.0;
myArray["SSN_3"] = 2.0;

for(... how? ...)
{
... Print ... but, how? ...
}
```

If you have any reference, please link.

Comment: No it is not....

Comment: With 4k rep, I would have expected a basic search to have been your first port of call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in [c](/questions/tagged/c) it's not possible, only integers are allowed.

Associative containers can be built with a simple struct like

```
struct double_map_item {
    char *key;
    double value;
};
```

take a look at [*bsearch()*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bsearch.3.html)'s manual page example for a simple method to find items through their key values.

Of course, this is a very simplistic possible implementation, for a more complete and robust implementation you should read about hash tables.

Regarding [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576752/is-it-possible-to-index-arrays-using-strings-or-characters/43576755#comment74203663_43576755), the type of a character constant in c is `int` and so

```
array['x'] = value;
```

is valid, but note that this is not really useful because,

1. You can only use a single character.
2. You will probably use an array with a size larger than needed.
3. You only have a very limited set of possible indices.

**NOTE**: following [your own comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576752/is-it-possible-to-index-arrays-using-strings-or-characters/43576755?noredirect=1#comment74203723_43576755), there is a chance that you saw c++ code. In c++ you can overload the `[]` operator so that it takes `const char *` as a parameter and then use a hash table or any other method to find the matching element for the given key.

But in c, it is not possible.

If one were to implement such a container in c++, the following example illustrate how to proceed, **please note** that this is just for illustration of the underlying concept, you should use [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) instead,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Array {
public:
    Array();
    double operator[](const char *const key);
    void insert(const char *const key, double value);

private:
    std::map<const char *, double> m_items;
};

Array::Array()
{
}

double
Array::operator[](const char *const key)
{
    return m_items[key];
}

void
Array::insert(const char *const key, double value)
{
    m_items.insert(std::pair<const char *, double>(key, value));
}

int
main(void)
{
    Array items;

    items.insert("SSN_1", 2.0);
    items.insert("SSN_2", 3.0);
    items.insert("SSN_3", 2.0);

    std::cout << items["SSN_1"] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Characters are an integer type, so they could work as indices (albeit not in a very useful way in most circumstances).

Comment: I think I saw somewhere, probably in string search algorithm implementations.

Comment: But not c, c++ because you can overload the `[]` operator.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi, oh, I get it. Can u give an example?

Comment: @anonymous Sorry but I am not that good with c++, and whenever I have tried to implement such operator overloading I always get stuck and have trouble, that's one of the reasons that I don't like c++, because it's impossible to really master it.